# Map Enum items to an anonymous type

Tags: c#

I have an extension to convert an Enum to a SelectList as follows:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum value, Object selected = null) {

  return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => 
    new { 
      Value = Convert.ToInt32(x), 
      Description = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description }
    ), "Value", "Description", selected);

}
```

This is applied as follows:

```
Countries = new CountryEnum().ToSelectList(currentCountry);
```

This works fine but in some cases I need to remove an item from the enum list or use a different order and I am not able to do that at the moment.

So I would like to have something maybe more flexible. For example:

```
new CountryEnum()
  .Map(x => new { 
    Value = Convert.ToInt32(x), 
    Name = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description
  )
  .OrderBy(x => x.Description)
  .Remove(x => x.Id > 30)
  .ToSelectList( ...
```

So basically I would like to have an Enum extension method that would map the enum to a IEnumerable of anonymous type to be used by other methods.

Does this make sense? How can I do this?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Map<T>(this Enum value, Func<Enum, T> expression) {

  Type type = value.GetType();

  IEnumerable<Enum> items = new List<Enum> { value };

  foreach (Enum item in items)
    yield return expression(item);

} // Map
```

And then use the following:

```
var items = new CountryEnum().Map(x => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(x) });
```

But this returns 0 ...

**UPDATE 2**

I think I solve the map part as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Map<T>(this Enum value, Func<Enum, T> expression) {

  Type type = value.GetType();

  var items = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>();

  foreach (Enum item in items)
    yield return expression(item);

}
```

Now I can use it as follows:

```
new CountryType()
.Map(x => new { 
  Id = Convert.ToInt32(x), 
  Description = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description })
.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
```

Now what I am missing is an extension method to convert this into a [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

The current extension I have is:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum value, Object selected = null) {

  return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => new { Value = Convert.ToInt32(x), Description = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description }), "Value", "Description", selected);

} // ToSelectList
```

So I would like to create an extension that would be applied after the Map one.

Comment: Why not just an extension method that maps any enum to an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>>? Why an anonymous type in the enumerator?

Comment: That would make sense if I would always want only the Enum id and Name. But sometimes I need Enum Id, Name, Description and maybe even another attribute.

Comment: I think all you have to do is add the parameters for the value and text field names to be passed to the `SelectedList` constructor.

Comment: Note that my select list extension is working ... But before that I need to make some manipulation on enum items.

Comment: The only way this works is if you change the method to take an `IEnumerable` that contains the values you want in the order you want them in.

Comment: If you need to filter the Enum values couldn't you pass a `Func<Enum, bool> filter` and call that before the select? A similar approach could be used for the order.

Comment: What is the definition of your `SelectList` class? Are you trying to get a list of all enum values, along with descriptions and other optional information such as sort order? Or do you want to fetch that information for a single enum value only?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I assume he's using `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`.

Comment: @petelids Yes I am using System.Web.Mvc.SelectList. I just added an Update 2. I was able to solve the Map part. Now I am looking to create a SelectList extension that will be applied after the map part.

Comment: Why don't you return an `IEnumerable<SelectList>` from your `Map` operation? Is there a specific reason that you need to use an anonymous type as an intermediate step?

Comment: @MDMoura - I might be missing something but I don't quite follow why you need the `Map` - can't you pass a `Func` to filter the enum values directly in your `ToSelectList` method?

Comment: @petelids Yes, That is also an option. Could you post some code? I wasn't sure how to implement that.

Comment: @petelids I am not sure how to invoke the func to filter before the select is called ... that was my problem. The same for orderBy

Comment: @MDMoura - sorry for the slow response, I've posted some code that I _think_ does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't want to map directly to a SelectList?

Something more like this:

```
public static SelectList MapToSelectList(this Enum value, 
                                         Func<Enum, SelectListItem> expression)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();

    var items = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>();

    return new SelectList(
        items.Select(i => expression(i)).ToList());
}
```

which would allow you to pass in a func that gives you control over how the enum is mapped to a SelectListItem like this:

```
SelectList mySelectList = new CountryType()
    .MapToSelectList(x => new SelectListItem { 
         Value = Convert.ToInt32(x), 
         Text = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an intermediate step but instead you can pass `Func`'s that do what you require to your existing `ToSelectList` method. You can filter the enums by using a `Func<Enum, bool>` and order using a `Func<Enum, T>`. Something like this should achieve what you are after:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(this Enum value, 
                                         Func<Enum, bool> filter, 
                                         Func<Enum, T> order,
                                         bool orderAsc = true,
                                         Object selected = null)
{
    //get all values from the enum
    IEnumerable<Enum> temp = Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).Cast<Enum>();

    //filter if required
    if (filter != null)
    {
        temp = temp.Where(filter);
    }

    //order if required
    if (order != null)
    {
        temp = orderAsc ? temp.OrderBy(order) : temp.OrderByDescending(order);
    }

    //map to a SelectList
    return new SelectList(temp.Select(x =>
        new
        {
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(x),
            Description = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description
        }), "Value", "Description", selected);
}
```

The above can then be called like this, for example, to only include any countries where the value of that country is greater than 30 with the results ordered by the description in ascending order and with `currentCountry` being the selected value:

```
var Countries = new CountryEnum().ToSelectList(x => Convert.ToInt32(x) > 30,
                                               x => x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description,
                                               true,
                                               currentCountry);
```

If you typically need the output ordered via the description in ascending order you could create a small wrapper method as a convenience like this:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum value, Func<Enum, bool> filter, Object selected = null)
{
    return value.ToSelectList(filter, x => x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description, true, selected);
}
```

Which would simplify the above call to something like this:

```
var Countries2 = new CountryEnum().ToSelectList(x => Convert.ToInt32(x) > 30, 
                                                currentCountry);
```